# Why NodeJS is not so fast in this example?

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I heard a lot about how fast NodeJS is. But my simple test case shows, that Apache with PHP is much faster. The codes look like this:

**PHP code**

```
require_once("mysqlconnect.php");
$start = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
$r = mysql_query("SELECT field1 FROM mytable");
$arr = array();
while($s = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
    $arr[] = $s;
}
$obj = json_encode($arr);
$end = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
echo $end-$start;
```

**NodeJS**

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
start = new Date().getTime(),
connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'root',
 password : 'root',
 database : 'testdb'
}),
json = '',
query = 'SELECT field1 FROM mytable';
connection.connect();
connection.query(query, function(err, results, fields) {
    json = JSON.stringify(results);
    var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    console.log(elapsed);
    connection.end();
});
```

The table contains 1000 rows and ten tests show that PHP even without any accelerators is at least 3 times faster. Why is that? Does it mean that NodeJS beats PHP only in some special cases?

Comment: 1) You included the time for the initial connection in JS, but not in PHP. 2) Most of the time here will be spent within the MySQL Server, so it is not really a good base for a comparison.

Comment: *Does it mean, that nodejs beats PHP only in some special cases?* No, it means that PHP beats Node at least in one special case, nothing else. (Which one is actually faster, I don't know, but based on one comparison you can't make any conclusions.)

Comment: In node, remove `connection.connect()` which is not necessary (or at least should be called with parameters), and move the getTime call to after `createConnection()` and you'll have a more fair test.

Comment: Also, you measure creating the MySQL connection in Node but not in PHP. (Probably won't make much of a difference though.)

Comment: @ Sirko. You are right. I have not noticed that. I've just run another 10 tests and see, that results are almost comparable

Comment: Though, PHP is still one tiny step ahead. All nodejs tests showed at least 30 milliseconds, while PHP showed 15-30 milliseconds

Comment: That can probably be explained by the timers' resolutions. You'd have to loop through the code at least several hundred times to create a valid test. Anything that happens that fast can't be reliably measured.

Comment: Also, currently as far as mysql node modules go, `mysql2` is much faster than `mysql`.

Comment: @mscdex I've just compared mysql and mysql2. You are absolutely right. mysql2 is much faster. Only now I see, that in my test case nodejs starts to win

Comment: node.js is about concurrency, not about one-shot scripts

Comment: @Jacobian You can use `process.hrtime` to measure time with higher resolution if you want.